# Remove navigation bar but keep the frame numbering

Tags: beamer, navigation

I don't like the navigation bar to be display so I add `\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty` to remove it, but it also remove the page numbering too. This is how I add the page numbering to the navigation bar.

```
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
    \hspace{1em}%
    \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=black}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{series=\bfseries}
```

Is there a way to remove the navigation bar but keep the frame numbering?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{%
    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
    \hspace{1em}%
    \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=black}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{series=\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```